# Is youth club available in Manager mode?

Tags: fifa-11

I played FIFA '07 way back in 2008. In manager mode the the youth club was present from where you could sometimes take some players and include them in your team.

I played FIFA '11 during last couple of days, and I tried to figure out where the youth club is without luck. Did EA remove that feature, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forums.electronicarts.co.uk/fifa-10-sony-playstation-3-microsoft-xbox-360/799963-youth-academy.html), EA removed that feature starting with FIFA 10, and [this thread](http://forum.ea.com/uk/posts/list/28443.page) suggests that it's gone in FIFA 11 as well (although perhaps only for consoles/PC; the PSP version apparently has a youth academy), so I don't think you're missing anything.

EA doesn't seem to list features that have been removed from games, so I haven't found any information about why it was removed or if it might be added for FIFA 12 or a subsequent console or PC release.

Answer (score 3):

After playing the game for a couple of weeks, I did not find youth club. I don't think that it's available, but someone can comment if he thinks otherwise.